# Generate rows from input array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume I have a table with many records called `comments`, and each record includes only a text body:

```sql
CREATE TABLE comments(id INT NOT NULL, body TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
INSERT INTO comments VALUES (generate_series(1,100), md5(random()::text));
```

Now, I have an input array with N substrings, with arbitrary length. For example:

```
abc
xyzw
123456
not_found
```

For each input value, I want to return **all** rows that match a certain condition.

For example, given that the table includes the following records:

```
| id | body        |
| -- | ----------- |
| 11 | abcd1234567 |
| 22 | unkown12    |
| 33 | abxyzw      |
| 44 | 12345abc    |
| 55 | found       |
```

I need a query that returns the following result:

```
| substring | comments.id | comments.body |
| --------- | ----------- | ------------- |
| abc       | 11          | abcd1234567   |
| abc       | 44          | 12345abc      |
| xyzw      | 33          | abxyzw        |
| 123456    | 11          | abcd1234567   |
```

So far, I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT substrings, comments.id, comments.body
FROM unnest(ARRAY[
  'abc',
  'xyzw',
  '123456',
  'not_found'
]) AS substrings
JOIN comments ON comments.id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM comments as inner_comments
  WHERE inner_comments.body LIKE ('%' || substrings || '%')
);
```

But the database client gets stuck for more than 10 minutes. And I missing something about joins?

Please note that this is a simplified example of my problem. My current check on the comment is not a `LIKE` statement, but a complex switch-case statement of different functions (fuzzy matching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detour with the `IN` is unnecessary and unless the optimizer can rewrite this and it likely cannot, adds overhead. Try if it gets better without.

```
SELECT un.substring,
       comments.id,
       comments.body
       FROM unnest(ARRAY['abc',
                         'xyzw',
                         '123456',
                         'not_found']) un (substring)
       INNER JOIN comments
                  ON comments.body LIKE ('%' || un.substring || '%');
```

But still indexes cannot be used here because of the wildcard at the beginning. You might want to look at [Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch.html) and see what options you have with it to improve the situation.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. I didn't know that you could name columns after an `unnest` call. Don't worry about the index; the `LIKE` condition is not actually used on my real-world problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are performing FULLTEXT search in a column that most likely doesn't have a FULLTEXT index.

A first step you could try would be to have your column "body" FULLTEXT indexed. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-fulltext-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and then perform the search using CONTAINS but, quite honestly, since you want to perform fuzzy matching you cannot rely on SQL server to perform the search - it would just not work properly. You will need an indexing service such as ElasticSearch, CloudSearch, Azure Search, etc

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem. If I run a query for a single value (not an array), like `SELECT id, body FROM comments WHERE comments.body LIKE ('%abcdef%');`, it takes no more than 100ms. I don't know, but shouldn't it take no more than 1 second for 4 records, instead of more than 10 minutes?

Comment: Please check @sticky bit solution but most likely you only have a couple of entries in your table. If it scales your perfomance even for a simple query using LIKE will deteriore fast...